# Apache / PHP - PHP not running - mod_php5 not found

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

Ok,

so PHP is not running, even though it is installed.
I am running Apache 2.4 on CentOs 7.

Here's my `/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf`

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule !prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
```

I can find these two modules in `/etc/httpd/modules` (as in `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules`) fine.

However, here's my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file

```
# mod_php options
<IfModule  mod_php5.c>
     #
     # Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
     #
     <FilesMatch \.php$>
          SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
     </FilesMatch>

     #
     # Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
     # files as PHP source code:
     #
     #<FilesMatch \.phps$>
     #    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
     #</FilesMatch>

     #
     # Apache specific PHP configuration options
     # those can be override in each configured vhost
     #
     php_value session.save_handler "files"
     php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
     php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
</IfModule>
```

I can't find the mod_php.c anywhere. It is not under `/modules/` or anywhere else.

Should I change the `<IFModule>` statement and use the `libphp5.so` instead of `mod_php5.c` ??

BTW: Both .conf files are loaded at the beginning of `/httpd.conf`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with an IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf directive commented out.

Regards,